# How to create a 100% stacked bar chart in R by counting data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar chart using ggplot that adds up difference scores and groups them with positive or negative values and then creates a graph of the percentage. I can't seem to figure out the right code to do this however and could use some guidance.

I have two columns I am focusing on: one for the grade level and then another column with the difference score. I tried summing up the values of positive and negative for an aggregate total, but kept running into errors manipulating that data.

I ended up making a new column and merged it to the data frame if the values in a row were less than or greater than 0. I was able to graph this, but I struggle to create a 100% stacked bar chart.

Ideally what I hope to do is to create a stacked bar chart with grades 6th - 10th in the X-axis and the y-axis being the percentage of students in that grade with a positive difference score against the % with a negative score.

```
# Attempting to create a new column of boolean values to create the chart
Pos_Neg_df <- c(Fall_Math_Data$RITDifference >0)
Percentage_Math_Data <- cbind(Fall_Math_Data, Pos_Neg_df)

# Plotted this

ggplot(Percentage_Math_Data) +geom_bar(aes(x = Grade, fill = Pos_Neg_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some sample data? It's difficult to see what exactly you're trying to do. That said, in your geom_bar, adding position = "stack" may be what you're looking for (see [ggplot2 documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html).)